# How to make website membership to be controlled from a web service or web api

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-membership

I would like to create a wcf web service or mvc web api as a data service, so it can be accessed from different clients. I would like to have the membership service in the data service as well, so when a user tries to log in on the web site, it will actually authenticate the user from the web service.

I was wondering if it was as simple as just putting a simple membership provider on the web service or web api. I got to a part where web service would return true or false based on whether the credentials are correct or not.

Would I be able to just use User.Identity.IsAutenticated just like I would in a regular mvc web sites? or do I need a further configurations?

I have been researching for a while but have not come across a detailed tutorial, yet.
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Integration of existing ASP.NET authentication systems with ASP.NET Web API is supported. For example, you can enable forms authentication for the site and apply the "[Authorize]" attribute to your Web API controller or individual action and this will do an authentication check prior to executing the Web API action.

Take a look at [this page](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security) for more details.

Comment: Thanks. But my question was if I would be able to use [authorize] tags or IsAuthenticated property in the website side by using the membership provider in web api side.

Comment: Let me try the following design to see if it would work for you.

You could create a standard ASP.NET MVC 4 site w/ the usual login page and wire that site up to a standard ASP.NET membership provider. Then, in the same site, you could add ASP.NET Web API controllers that act as your data service. In these controllers you could use the "[Authorize]" attribute to authenticate requests.

Maybe this is what you're after?